# Total sum of multiple mysql rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My question is how to get the total sum of multiple rows. Below is my score table with the user score for each round.

---

```
| Username | Round | Score |
----------------------------
| Uame_1   |   1   |   4   |
| Uame_2   |   1   |   5   |
| Uame_1   |   2   |   8   |
| Uame_2   |   2   |   3   |
```

I want the total user score from all rounds and update it into a table like below.

```
--------------------------
| Username | Total_score |
--------------------------
| Uame_1   |      12     |
| Uame_2   |      8      |
```

Comment: That's a fairly simple `GROUP BY` operation.

Comment: Don't store the sum in another table.  Calculate it when you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT `Username`, SUM(`Score`) as Total_score FROM table_name GROUP BY `Username`
```